# Hanging Mapreduce job while reading hbase tables

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata, distributed-computing

I have a 4 node  hadoop distributed cluster (including hbase) set up like this.

- **node1**- namenode + hbase master + zookeeper
- **node2**- resourcemanager
- **node3**- datanode1+hbase regionserver1+nodemanager
- **node4**- datenode2+hbase regionserver2+nodemanager

Cluster set up seems to be fine , as all the WEB UIs (hbase, namenode, resource manager ) are coming up . Now when I am trying to submit a mapreduce job which reads/writes hbase tables , it gets hanged. It keeps getting timeedout
**However same job is working fine , in case I explicitly mention hbase credentials in my mapreduce code and set them in job**

```
Configuration conf =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.211.55.101");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
conf.set("hbase.master", "10.211.55.101:60000");
//10.211.55.101 is the ipaddress of node1
```

These properties are already set in hbase configuration on node1 , node3 and node4.  Now my question is **Do I need to set up anything with regards to hbase configs on node2 where only resource manager is running ? Why the same job is working fine when hbase configs are set in code explicity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBaseConfiguration.create() method loads the configurations in hbase-site.xml. Make sure you have hbase-site.xml available in the classpath of Node2.

Below is specified in HBase documentation [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/config.files.html)

> The configuration used by a Java client is kept in an
>   HBaseConfiguration instance. The factory method on HBaseConfiguration,
>   HBaseConfiguration.create();, on invocation, will read in the content
>   of the first hbase-site.xml found on the client's CLASSPATH, if one is
>   present (Invocation will also factor in any hbase-default.xml found;
>   an hbase-default.xml ships inside the hbase.X.X.X.jar)

Comment: Thanks Ramana...am stil trying to make it work.. ..does RM node (node2 in my case) needs just the hbase-site.xml in classpath or any other entity in classpath  ?  One more question, I know generally in real world use- cases , we maintain separate clusters for mapreduce and hbase . ..I understand that mean node managers and region servers are running on different nodes in different clusters ...so in this case, data locality will always be a problem whenever running mapreduce job..am I right ?

Comment: No. Typically, Region server is co-located with HDFS data node. That's the reason HBase gives better performance.